# Passing function with parameters in ng-class to get the class

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use ng-class of angular. I have a function which returns the class based on the parameters we send it. How can i achieve it ?

Here's what i tried:

```
<div ng-class="{ getClass(key) }" >
```

and in the controller:

```
getClass = function(keyVal){
    angular.forEach(myArray, function(value, id){
        if(value.key === keyVal){
            console.log(value.class);
            return value.class;
        }
    });
}
```

Just returning a string works. but the moment I add this anfular.forEach, it stops. In debugger, the loop is working fine and returning the right data.

I know it can be acheved by a filter, but I want to do this way only.

Comment: use double curly brace and check <div ng-class="{{ getClass(key) }}" >

Comment: can you add your array also?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You shoud not use single curly-brackets, simply remove them and it will work:

```
<div ng-class="getClass(key)">
```

However for your use case it is even simpler to write the expression directly into the HTML (instead of calling a function)

```
<div ng-class="key + '-class'">
```

Keep in mind that the ng-class expression can return

1. a string: `"class1 class2 class3"`
2. an array: `["class1", "class2", "class3"]`
3. a map: `"{class1: true, class2: true, class3: true}"`

### Update

Your new problem is different. When you return something inside `angular.forEach`, it just exit the loop but it is not returned by the function getClass. So keep a reference to it:

```
getClass = function(keyVal) {
    var theClass;
    angular.forEach(myArray, function(value, id) {
        if(value.key === keyVal) {
            theClass = value.class;
        }
    });
    return theClass;
}
```

Or you can have a simpler version:

```
getClass = function(keyVal) {
  for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if (myArray[i].key === keyVal) {
      return myArray[i].class;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey !  I tried this. But it is not working. In debugger the function returns the class, but it is not reflecting in HTML.

Comment: Your question has changed, I've updated my answer, it should be working now. PS: are you sure in the debugger that getClass returns the class, or do you just see your console.log *inside* the forEach?

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

You can achieve this by like this

```
myapp.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {


      $scope.getClass = function(a){
            return a;
      } 
});
```

and in template

```
    <div ng-class="getClass('red')">text</div>
```

[**See My full working updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nisham/mgPGS/121/)

Comment: What if i want it to be called when template is rendered ?

Comment: I tried this. In my case, when simply returning something, it works. But I am using a `angular.forEach` too. After I add that, it stopped working. IN debugger, it sends correct value. But it is not reflecting on the HTML.

Comment: @charger73 dont return from forEach callback..set some variable..return value from getClass method

Answer (score 0):

You are returning value from callback function of for each method..which not correct..because u r expected return value from getclass method
Try this

```
  $scope.getclass =function(k){
  Var c="";
   angular.foreach(arr,function(v){
   //to do
      c=k;
   });

    return c;
   };
```