# Changing classes in AngularJS for multiple elements

Tags: jquery, angularjs, cordova

I have a puzzle app I am writing in Apache Cordova and AngularJS. The puzzle is made up of a grid, with multiple 'lights' in each grid square.

[image]

When you mouseover one of the lights, certain areas will light up. I have this working fine in standard jQuery, with a mouseover event bound to the class, but I am struggling to get it working in AngularJS. I could include full jQuery in the project - but that feels like cheating.

So far I have the following directive:-

```
app.directive('etkHighlight', function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            element.on("mouseenter", function () {
                var id = attr.cage;
                var el = angular.element(document).find(id);
                el.addClass("etk-light-on");
                console.log("enter")
            })
            element.on("mouseleave", function () {
                var id = attr.cage;
                console.log("enter")
            })
        }
    }
});
```

with the HTML looking like:-

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="etk-key" id="cage-t">T</div>
    <div class="etk-light etk-base-left etk-light-off" data-cage="cage-k" etk-Highlight>k</div>
    <div class="etk-light etk-base-right etk-light-off" data-cage="cage-m" etk-Highlight>m</div>
</div>
```

I am getting the id of the object I need to change class OK, and el is populated with *something* but the addClass fails to actually add the class.

What am I doing wrong? Is this even the right way to approach this? Ideally I want something I can use to manage the class changes for the mouseover of all the lights.

Plnkr:- http://plnkr.co/edit/JjwucC3HECN9Mmm4S3Ib NB only the lights labelled l, k & m on the top row are set up to use the directive

**UPDATE** I've realised I've not defined the issue too well. When I mouseover, for example, the light labelled 'l', I want to change the class of both that light, and the 'L' square found to the right and down....

Comment: adding class element? can't you use ng-class="{'class': result/expresion}", like ng-class="{'green': item=1}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will work, I've used `enter` and `leave` in `html` to pass `class`  names to be attached to, and in `link` function of the `directive` retrieving them as `attrs.enter` & `attrs.leave`

`*.html` file :-

```
<body ng-app='app'>
  <div etk-highlight enter='red' leave='black'>test</div>
</body>
```

`*.js` file :-

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])
.directive('etkHighlight', function () {

return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.on("mouseenter", function () {
          element.removeClass(attrs.leave);
          element.addClass(attrs.enter);
        });
        element.on("mouseleave", function () {
            element.removeClass(attrs.enter);
            element.addClass(attrs.leave);
        });
    }
}
});
```

`*.css` file :-

```
.red {
  color:red;
}

.black {
  color:black;
}
```

Comment: This is really close! But it's made me realise I haven't explained the whole requirement too well. See update :-/

Comment: Your answer pointed me in the right direction - I just had to amend how I found the linked element

`element.on("mouseenter", function () {
                    element.removeClass(attrs.leave);
                    element.addClass(attrs.enter);

                    var id = attrs.cage;
                    var el = angular.element(document.querySelector('#' + id));
                    el.removeClass(attrs.leave);
                    el.addClass(attrs.enter);
                });`

Answer (score 1):

To alter classes in angular you should take a look at the ng-class directive that comes bundled with Angular:

[Angular ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

In short your add class code will be removed and you will use angular's way of changing styles.
For example

And then in your code set highlight variable to true/false depending on the click. Take a look at the example also with the docs and adjust it accordingly.

Comment: I've looked at that, but unless I'm misunderstanding the documentation I believe I would need to add a specific class to each element i.e `<div class="etk-key" id="cage-s" ng-class="cage-s-class">S</div>` and add ng-mouseover to all the lights. This just struck me as overkill for something that I can do in jQuery as
   `$('.etk-light').mouseenter(function() {
    var cageId = $(this).data("cage");
    $('#'+cageId).addClass("etk-light-on");   
    $(this).removeClass("etk-light-off");
    $(this).addClass("etk-light-on");
    });`

Comment: I would still prefer to call a function, as suggested here: [other answer] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28208165/passing-function-with-parameters-in-ng-class-to-get-the-class) You can call getClass with the id of your div. It is the angular way of doing things, so might be worth looking at.

Answer (score 1):

i worked on your pen something is not right with the code i have to go more into it.also replaced your directive with other but still thats not working.you can go for ng-class,ng-mouseenter or ng-mouseleave as well.or you can also use ng-style or pass a function into style attribute.

```
directives.directive('showonhoverparent',
   function() {
      return {
         link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.parent().bind('mouseenter', function() {
                element.show();
            });
            element.parent().bind('mouseleave', function() {
                 element.hide();
            });
       }
   };
});
```

Hope that works for you and i will look into your code  more deeply for finding the exact issue.